# how to give name in auto submit form javascript

Tags: javascript, php

This is my code that I am using to submit form with post value

```
 <form action="<?php echo DOMAIN; ?>contact/booking-form.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" />
    <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit"  />
    <script>document.getElementById('submit').submit();</script>  
  </form>
```

Can anybody help me to pass `name="submit"` value of submit button to another page?

Comment: There is not submit button in your markup..

Comment: i want to add name of submit button with given code

Comment: Are you able to see your form? Seems to me it is getting submitted as soon as it appears in the DOM.

Comment: @ranbir, There is no submit button in your code...

Comment: Is your intention to submit form on page load? Instead submit button, add hidden field and check its value on second page, maybe...

Comment: i want to pass name="submit" to another page there i have isset($_POST['submit'])

Comment: you are not setting the `value` attribute of `submit` button. see [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php). plus, you're not submitting the form with `<script>document.getElementById('submit').submit();</script>` since `submit()` method is used for `form` elements, not buttons. plusplus; you need to rename the submit button to something else other than  `submit` or you'll get a `submit is not a function` error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A submit button is only going to be a successful control if it is used to submit the form (and even then only if it has a name and a value … which yours does not).

If you want `submit=submit` in your form data when you submit the form with JavaScript, then don't use a submit button to put that data in the form in the first place. Use a hidden input.

```
<input type="submit">
<input type="hidden" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit">
```

Then you have two other problems.

First, submit is a method of form elements, not inputs. So you need to change your script to call the right element.

```
<script>document.getElementById('submit').form.submit();</script>
```

Second, if a form has a control called `submit` then that will clobber the `submit` method. So you need to get one from a different form (not supported in old versions of Internet Explorer):

```
<script>
var form = document.getElementById('submit').form;
var submit_method = document.createElement("form").submit;
submit_method.call(form);
</script>
```

Comment: i just want to pass **name=submit** of input type=submit to another page , there i have ` if(isset($_POST['submit']))`

Comment: i think its working quentin , you are genius
let me check with more fields
you know i always watch your tutorials on you tube(if you are same)

Answer (score 0):

```
     <form id=submit action="<?php echo DOMAIN; ?>contact/booking-form.php" name="form1" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" />
    <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" />

  </form>
<script >
        document.form1.submit()

    </script>
```

Comment: no, its not working for me,  
i want to give name in submit button , that will work on next redirected page booking-form.php

Comment: not working , 
i want to pass '<input type="submit" **name="submit"** />'
to another page and there i have `if(isset($_POST['submit']))`

Answer (score 0):

there is no sumit button in your code. first add in html

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit"/>
<script>
  document.getElementById("submit").value = "newSubmitButtonValue";
</script>
```

Comment: Could you explain how your answer addresses the problem(s) from the question? Code-only answers are not very useful, especially for further readers that stumble upon this post. Thanks!

Comment: @Cristik yes the question is not proper

Comment: i want to pass `<input type="submit" **name="submit"** >` to another page there i have `if(isset($_POST['submit']))`